# How do I auto-place new items in columns with Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, hugo, tailwind-css

I have the following code for my Hugo page for listing out new posts, formatted with Tailwind CSS:

```
{{ define "main" }}
{{ range .Pages }}
<div class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-3">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
            <div class="bg-white shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
                <div class="bg-cover bg-center h-56 p-4" style="background-image: url(https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe&size=512)">
                    <div class="flex justify-end">
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-4">
                    <p class="uppercase tracking-wide text-sm font-bold text-gray-700">{{ .Params.Major}}</p>
                    <p class="text-3xl text-gray-900 font-bold">{{ .Title }}</p>
                    <p class="text-gray-700">A small description and a bucnch of stuff.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex p-4 border-t border-gray-300 text-gray-700">
                    <div class="flex-1 inline-flex items-center">
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 fill-current mr-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path d="M15.573,11.624c0.568-0.478,0.947-1.219,0.947-2.019c0-1.37-1.108-2.569-2.371-2.569s-2.371,1.2-2.371,2.569c0,0.8,0.379,1.542,0.946,2.019c-0.253,0.089-0.496,0.2-0.728,0.332c-0.743-0.898-1.745-1.573-2.891-1.911c0.877-0.61,1.486-1.666,1.486-2.812c0-1.79-1.479-3.359-3.162-3.359S4.269,5.443,4.269,7.233c0,1.146,0.608,2.202,1.486,2.812c-2.454,0.725-4.252,2.998-4.252,5.685c0,0.218,0.178,0.396,0.395,0.396h16.203c0.218,0,0.396-0.178,0.396-0.396C18.497,13.831,17.273,12.216,15.573,11.624 M12.568,9.605c0-0.822,0.689-1.779,1.581-1.779s1.58,0.957,1.58,1.779s-0.688,1.779-1.58,1.779S12.568,10.427,12.568,9.605 M5.06,7.233c0-1.213,1.014-2.569,2.371-2.569c1.358,0,2.371,1.355,2.371,2.569S8.789,9.802,7.431,9.802C6.073,9.802,5.06,8.447,5.06,7.233 M2.309,15.335c0.202-2.649,2.423-4.742,5.122-4.742s4.921,2.093,5.122,4.742H2.309z M13.346,15.335c-0.067-0.997-0.382-1.928-0.882-2.732c0.502-0.271,1.075-0.429,1.686-0.429c1.828,0,3.338,1.385,3.535,3.161H13.346z"></path>
                    </svg>
                        <p><span class="text-gray-900 font-bold">3rd</span> Year</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-1 inline-flex items-center">
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 fill-current mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M17.03 21H7.97a4 4 0 0 1-1.3-.22l-1.22 2.44-.9-.44 1.22-2.44a4 4 0 0 1-1.38-1.55L.5 11h7.56a4 4 0 0 1 1.78.42l2.32 1.16a4 4 0 0 0 1.78.42h9.56l-2.9 5.79a4 4 0 0 1-1.37 1.55l1.22 2.44-.9.44-1.22-2.44a4 4 0 0 1-1.3.22zM21 11h2.5a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-9.06a4.5 4.5 0 0 1-2-.48l-2.32-1.15A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 8.56 10H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h8.06c.7 0 1.38.16 2 .48l2.32 1.15a3.5 3.5 0 0 0 1.56.37H20V2a1 1 0 0 0-1.74-.67c.64.97.53 2.29-.32 3.14l-.35.36-3.54-3.54.35-.35a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 3.15-.32A2 2 0 0 1 21 2v9zm-5.48-9.65l2 2a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-2-2zm-10.23 17A3 3 0 0 0 7.97 20h9.06a3 3 0 0 0 2.68-1.66L21.88 14h-7.94a5 5 0 0 1-2.23-.53L9.4 12.32A3 3 0 0 0 8.06 12H2.12l3.17 6.34z"></path>
                        </svg>
                        <p><span class="text-gray-900 font-bold"></span> Programming</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4 pt-3 pb-4 border-t border-gray-300 bg-gray-100">
                    <div class="text-xs uppercase font-bold text-gray-600 tracking-wide">Made By</div>
                    <div class="flex items-center pt-2">
                        
                        <div>
                            <p class="font-bold text-gray-900">Aman Bhargava</p>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

What I want is to have three columns of cards, with each new post being added left to right in the columns before adding a new row below. However, my code gives me a stacked listing instead of the expected output:

[image]

I would like something like this:

| 1st Column | 2nd Column | 3rd Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First Post | Second Post | Third Post |
| Fourth Post | Fifth Post | Sixth Post |

Comment: With the above code I'm able to replicate the desired behaviour you mentioned in [play.tailwindcss.com](https://play.tailwindcss.com/). Is there additional CSS that might be causing the issue?

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you for your response! Hugo uses something called partials to build pages, so this bit of the page is inserted into the main `base` template. This is what that looks like: https://pastebin.com/X8E8RHXG (The part where the list gets included is on line 19). The only additional CSS I can see is `<div class="my-1 w-full overflow-hidden lg:w-5/6 xl:w-5/6 bg-gray-200 pt-5 items-center">`

Comment: Sadly, I still can't reproduce the issue with the additional HTML.

Comment: @juliomalves Sorry about this. I've uploaded the entire repo, hopefully that is of more help. This particular file is here: https://github.com/thedivtagguy/srishtiarchives/blob/master/themes/archives/layouts/_default/list.html

Comment: @juliomalves did you have any luck with this? I've started a bounty on the question and would be happy to award it to you if you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the range function is outside the grid, so it's creating a new grid for each card.  You probably want just one grid, with all the cards placed within it.

If you move your range function inside the grid, so that it iterates only over the cards, e.g.:

```
{{ define "main" }}
<div class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-3">
  {{ range .Pages }}
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <div class="bg-white shadow-xl rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ end }}
</div>
{{ end }}
```

then you should get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! This has been an issue for the past 4 days and I had absolutely no idea what was going on. Your answer works perfectly. I shall revisit this answer and award the bounty in 15 hours, after it is unlocked. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You're welcome. Can I suggest adding the hugo tag, and consider a title revision to "How do I place grid items in columns using Hugo and Tailwind CSS?", which may help others with a similar issue find the question.